# Getting "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined error while calling reset()" in vue JS in below file

Tags: vue.js

Getting below error while calling reset as per the screenshot:-

```
> vue.esm.js:1897 TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
>            at c.setResults (store.js:61)
>            at vuex.esm.js:785
>            at vuex.esm.js:407
>            at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
>            at vuex.esm.js:406
>            at c.NYxO.c._withCommit (vuex.esm.js:565)
>            at c.NYxO.c.commit (vuex.esm.js:405)
>            at commit (vuex.esm.js:350)
>            at c.reset (store.js:41)
>            at Array.<anonymous> (vuex.esm.js:792)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please replace screenshots with a formatted code blocks

Comment: Getting formatting error while uploading the code block, So attached image.

Answer (score 0):

when you are calling the `reset()`.

`store.commit('SearchResult',[])` executing with an empty array,

but into `setResults:(state, results)`, here `results` is an empty array so results has no `siteList` attribute. so this is the cause of error.

so consider the `setResults` function code when `results` is an empty array.

Comment: Hi Md Mahamudul Hasan Do u mean to say   I have to call store.dispatch('setResults');Could you  please elaborate as I am not form Frontend background.

Comment: provide the code or prepare codepan otherwise difficult to write code

Comment: Check if you are able to access from below link:  https://codepen.io/amitrolly/pen/qBawqvp

Comment: i shall check and reply little later

Comment: you can use this solution, but code not written in good way, just temporary solution
https://codepen.io/mahamudul-hasan-the-looper/pen/poEBrGq